# Segmentation of microscopic images

Tags: image-segmentation

This is a classical image segmentation problem: I need to make a visual measurement of particles.
I've been using watershed, kmeans and mean shift but it doesn't work well on this image. Could you please recommend me some other methods/open source code?

P/S: Any manual/semi automatic segmentation is also ok with me. I just need the correct segmentation in a reasonable not time consuming way.

[image]

Comment: Could you manually segment a few particles to give us an idea of what you require? P.S. next time upload a smaller image to reduce page load time, I have adjusted this one for you :)

Comment: I don't even know how to count these particles with my eyes and brain.  Which things are particles and which are just lumps on particles?

Comment: Maybe you want to try some form of trainable segmentation...

Answer (score 1):

Since it is very hard to guess what result you *need*, proposing any automatic segmentation method is very hard.

Let me instead propose two different semi-automatic *segmentation with markers*.

1. **Segmentation using Minimum Spanning Forests with markers**

   This method is based on a version of watershed [[Cousty et. al.: *Watershed Cuts: Minimum Spanning Forests and the Drop of Water Principle*, 2009]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4564470).

   Basically, you calculate a version of watershed (there are many versions), called *watershed cuts*, which gives you a (pretty severe) over-segmentation.

   After that, you mark your one object (or all of your objects, 1 marker per object + 1 for the background if there is any) you want to find, and it calculates the most likely segmentation based on pre-calculated watershed.

   I don't want to go into details, since there is pseudo-code and example images provided (one is even a cell image) in the article, but if you want me please leave a comment and I can add some more information.
2. **Segmentation using $\alpha$-trees (or $\alpha$-connected components) with markers**

   Here, the "starting over-segmentation" is actually simply the segmentation to flat-zones (equal-intensity areas in the image). I am going to explain a little bit of theory here.

   An $\alpha$-connected component of a pixel $p$, or $\alpha$-$CC(p)$ is obtained as follows:

   - first you choose a connectivity (4- or 8-conn.; 4-conn simply means the neighbors of a pixel are *up, down, left,* and *right*)
   - if the intensity difference between two neighboring pixels is $\leq \alpha$, those pixels are connected
   - $\alpha$-$CC(p)$ contains all the pixels connected to pixel $p$ as well as all the pixels that can be reached from pixel $p$ through a connected path

   Now, for various reasons (I can expand the answer again if somebody asks), if you follow the $\alpha$-$CC$ around one pixel, its area usually grows slowly as you increase the $\alpha$, then at some point you have a sudden and rapid increase in the area, and then it continues to grow slowly. Usually, if you look at the $\alpha$-$CC$ just in the moment *before* the rapid size increase, it will give you your object.

   Again, you can use markers to mark which $\alpha$-$CC$'s you want to "follow". The advantage here is that you can calculate the $\alpha$-hierarchy once and then do all the calculations on the same hierarchy.

   I know it sounds a bit confusing with all the new terms unless you know something about $\alpha$-trees, but here's some references to help:

   - [Najman, Soille: *On Morphological Hierarchical Representations for Image Processing and Spatial Data Clustering*, 2012](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-32313-3_4) - a good reference for $\alpha$-hierarchies in general
   - [Serna, Marcotegui: *Attribute Controlled Reconstruction and Adaptive Mathematical Morphology*, 2013](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-38294-9_18) - these guys have done something very similar to what I am proposing. One of the proposed and explored usages in their article is segmentation (they're just using more attributes, not just area).
   - [Merciol, Lefevre: *Fast Image and Video Segmentation Based on Alpha-tree Multiscale Representation*, 2012](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6395114) - this is more or less exactly the usage I described.